# SQL query error when creating a table in PostgreSQL /SpringBoot

Tags: spring, postgresql

I am using Spring Boot and PostgreSQL to create a table in which I want to insert the latest data from another table.

I was using H2 and everything was fine but when I migrated to PostgreSQL, the error "SELECT ... FROM must be followed by a reference to the table appeared e.g. SELECT * FROM table as FOO" .

However, when modifying my query with AS, I am still having the same error.

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS EOD AS " +
                        "(SELECT ID, " +
                        "CUSIP, " +
                        "NAME, " +
                        "ISIN, " +
                        "NAV, " +
                        "RIC, " +
                        "RTV," +
                        "VOLATILITY as volatility, " +
                        "CURRENCY as currency, "+
                        "ASK_ISSUER as ask_issuer, " +
                        "ASK_KECH as ask_kech, " +
                        "AVERAGE_SCORE as average_score, " +
                        "BID_ISSUER as bid_issuer, " +
                        "BID_KECH as bid_kech, " +
                        "BID_ONLY as bid_only, " +
                        "CREATOR as creator, " +
                        "DECENTER as decenter, " +
                        "DENOMINATION as denomination, " +
                        "FORCE_PUBLISH as force_publish, " +
                        "ISSUER_SPREAD as issuer_spread, " +
                        "KECH_MARGIN as kech_margin, " +
                        "KECH_SPREAD as kech_spread, " +
                        "DISTANCE_TO_BANDS_SCORE as distance_to_bands_score, " +
                        "DIFFERENCE_TO_LEXIFI_PRICE_SCORE as difference_to_lexifi_price_score, " +
                        "METRIC_C as metric_c, " +
                        "PRICE_EXPRESSION as price_expression, " +
                        "PRODUCT_TYPE as product_type, " +
                        "PUBLISHED as published, " +
                        "PUBLISHING as publishing, " +
                        "TIMESTAMP as timestamp " +
                        "FROM " +
                        "(" +
                        "SELECT * FROM RTDATABASE AS T " +
                        "JOIN (SELECT MAX(CONVERT(TIMESTAMP, DATETIME)) AS LATESTDATE FROM T GROUP BY ISIN)" +
                        ") tm " +
                        "WHERE CONVERT(tm.TIMESTAMP, DATETIME) = tm.LATESTDATE) AS LATESTDATA;";
```

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Many thanks in advance !

Comment: The final `AS LATESTDATA` does not make any sense to me, and there is no such `CONVERT` function in PostgreSQL. Perhaps you should tell us what you are trying to achieve with this statement.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, this is a SQL script. I want to take the latest inputs in RTDATABASE for today's date and inject them in the EOD database which should be created if it doesn't exist. This query works perfectly with H2.

Comment: Well H2 and Postgres are two very different databases. The `convert()` function Postgres is used to convert character sets in Postgres. What do you expect `CONVERT(tm.TIMESTAMP, DATETIME)` to do? And what data type is the `timestamp` column? And is `datetime` also a column?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: the final `AS LATESTDATA` was probably added because of the useless parentheses around the complete SELECT

Comment: Thanks for your reply I want to convert the type of the column to timestamp to compare the values in the column.

Comment: My problem is: select all the columns from rtdatabase when the timestamp is the latest in the table for a given value of the ISIN

Comment: I just "translated" all my SQL queries to postgreSQL queries and it worked... many thanks !